# How can I find the median of 5 variables in Python?

Tags: python

I have to find the median of 5 randoms variables only using if and else.
I don't understand why this code isn't working. I am new to python and beginning programming. If you can help me out that would be very great :D

[image: code]

Comment: Why can you only use if and else? This is an extremely tedious and hard-coded method to solve a relatively simple problem

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you tried sorting the list of 5 values and taking the 3rd? This sounds like a homework problem. 

Comment: yes this is a homework problem I don't hide it. Well its because its a homework I can only use if and else:P sorting the list of 5 without while would be so long... Trying to find something else

Comment: Please try to avoid including screenshots of code. Paste it in as text, instead.

Comment: Sure sorry, it is my first question here on stackoverflow, thank you for the advice.

Comment: If and else won't work in every scenario. HINT: Median is the middle value of SORTED list if the length of list is odd else it is the average of two middle values of SORTED list

Comment: I don't know why all the answers import when the question says you can only use if and else? You could literally just write your own code using more than if and else and make a package, import, and use. The correct answer should be writing your own sorting algorithm, and finding the median after.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my approach (generalised):

```
list_1 = [1,3,3,8,9]
list_1.sort()
list_len=len(list_1)
if list_len%2==0:
   print((list_1[list_len]+list_1[list_len-1])/2)
else:
   print(list_1[(list_len-1)//2])
```

Comment: I agree that the sort is the best approach, but I think the question states that only if/else statements can be used.

Comment: Okay. I will add that as well.

Comment: I see, does it sort by ascii number ?

Comment: With a purely numerical list, it sorts by value of the integers.

Comment: if you need to convert numbers in ascii in the range between o and 9 there is no problem. If the numbers are composed by more than 1 digit, then you should convert them before.

Answer (score 1):

There is [Numpy.median](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.median.html)

That will just give you the median given an array.

```
import numpy as np

a = 2
b = 4
c = 1
d = 10
e = 12

np.median([a,b,c,d,e])
```

Produces:

```
4.0
```

Comment: Yes same as above I don't think I can import but thank you:)

Answer (score 1):

The *numpy* and *statistics* Python libraries have *median* functions.

Using **[numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.median.html)** *(Python 2.x+)*

```
>>> from numpy import median
>>> median([1,2,3,4,5])
3.0
```

Using **[statistics](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.median)** *(Python 3.x+)*

```
>>> from statistics import median
>>> median([1,2,3,4,5])
3.0
```